# Cloud or In-house

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am assigned a task to find a way to reduce the computing cost. We are using AWS at the moment. 
The work we do involves a lot of calculation in excel spreadsheets using VBA modules. The result will be inserted into database.
My question is that is it common for companies that do a lot of excel calculations  to have their own dedicate computing server in house? Is it in general worth investigating as a cost saving method?

A bit extra information to make my question more relevant. 
1. Our db size is about 4tb. It is not very big in some sense but it contains a lot of rows. Some of tables have 1000000000+ rows.
2. Each excel run would process 1 million rows of data. A lot of formulas and custom vba modules are involved in producing the result. We run 20~30 such excel process every month. 
3. Db server is already under pressure with all the etl running in the background so we won't be able to move the calc into it.

As some have pointed out that it is indeed a very broad question. Whether in house process suits us depends on more detailed analysis. I am asking just to find out what other approaches are  people taking. 
Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here. There are just too many factors.  Besides amount of work ( does "lot of calculation" mean for you capacity of a pc? 10 pcs? 1000?) and its distribution over time you also need to consider local salaries and electricity cost...

Comment: This is odd, why do not transfer calculation in application server? Or in database?